# Joomla JCE editor removes <canvas> element on save

Tags: joomla, html5-canvas

I use html 5 canvas with some javascript in joomla articles - JCE editor.
When I save the article, the editor removes the canvas element, only javascript remains.

I disabled all cleanup in jce:
Editor global configuration: validate html: no
Editor profiles -> Default -> Editor Parameters -> Cleanup & Output: Validate html: no

In Advanced options all is allowed (javascript, css, php, xhtml)
Joomla text filter: no filtering

and JCE stil removes this canvas line:

```
<canvas  id="name" width="1170" height="400"></canvas>
```

I currently use Sourcerer plugin, but I don't like it because no code is highlighted.

Joomla 3.4, JCE 2.4.6

Answer (score 1):

Try the following.

Go to

**Extensions** >> **Plugin Manager** >> **TinyMCE** >> **Valid Elements**

The add `canvas` to the textarea.

Comment: This is for TinyMCE, I want to use JCE because of other Editors and other functions